# Is there any possibility for a workaround to PostgreSQL 32760 bind parameters limitation?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have a JPA method in my repository trying to find entities with a where clause. The problem is that i have huge data set, and when i try to send more than 32k elements in the list clause, i received an error. I found that is a PostgreSQL driver limitation, but i cant find a workaround.

I tried `Pageable` request but is hard to send only 30k for 8 millions record. Is there any possibility to send more than 30k objects in my in list where clause?

```
List<Object> findAllByIdIn(List<Long> ids)
```

Comment: Insert all IDs to a temp table, when use `where x.ID in ( select ID from TempIDs )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't want to do it especially if you plan to send 8 million identifiers. Working around the `IN` statement or bind parameter limit is inefficient. Consider the following:

1. Thousands of bind parameters will result in megabytes of SQL. It will take considerable time to send the SQL text to the database. In fact the database might take longer to read the SQL text than execute the query as per [Tom's answer to "Limit and conversion very long IN list: WHERE x IN ( ,,, ...)" question](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:778625947169).
2. SQL parsing will be inefficient. Not only the megabytes of SQL text take time to read but with increased bind parameter count each query will usually have a distinct number of bound parameters used. This distinct bound parameter count is going to result in each query being parsed and planned separately (see [this article which explains it](https://vladmihalcea.com/improve-statement-caching-efficiency-in-clause-parameter-padding/)).
3. There is a hard limit of bound parameters in a SQL statement. You just discovered it, 32760.

For those types of queries it's usually better to create [temporary tables](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-temporary-table/). Create a new temporary table before your query, insert all the identifiers into it and join it with the entity table. This join will be equivalent to `IN` condition except SQL text will be short.

It's important to understand from where are these 8 million identifiers loaded. If you are pulling these from the database in the previous query just to pass them back to the the next query you most likely want to write a stored procedure. There is possibly a flaw in your current approach, JPA is not always the right tool for the job.